# Windows Store Multilingual Language change

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, multilingual

I'm using the Multilingual toolkit in Visual Studio 2013 on a 8.1 C#/XAML project.
I have a couple of languages and hooked up the following event:

> protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args){
>       ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValues_MapChanged;
>   ...

I expect when I change my language my handler:

> ```
>    private void QualifierValues_MapChanged(IObservableMap<string, string> sender, IMapChangedEventArgs<string> @event)
>    {
>        ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
>    }
> ```

will reset the language. But it makes my app crash. Just In Time Debugger and I don't really know what's the issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Output Windows shows:
The program '[11556] MyApp.exe' has exited with code -1073741795 (0xc000001d) 'Illegal Instruction'.

Answer (score 0):

Seems all a bit out of context.

Did you read through this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967758.aspx

This might be helpful too:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2013/03/26/howto-refresh-languages-winrt-xaml-windows-store.aspx

Comment: Not that helpfull, 1 I'm using C#/XAMl and not HTML5 / Javascript and 2 Tim Heuer his post is outdated since I'm working on a 8.1 app. Visual Studio underlines the code and says it's obsolete.

Comment: You might have to add little meat to your question